# Warning while running Firefox in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

While running a selenium java program I got a Warning stated as follow:

```
(firefox:8841): WARNING : 11:35:06.806: No marshaller for signature of signal 'PropertiesChanged'
```

I am using **CentOs 7**. I don't have any clue about it. I tried googling it but no help.

Comment: Presumably you are on Ubuntu, are your tests affected for this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: I am using centOs 7. Can you tell me the reason for this Warning? @DebanjanB

Comment: @JeffC The user is a _New contributor_ and may not be accustomed with the site rules. There was absolutely no necessity to **bold** certain words within the comment. A _CV_ and/or a _DV_ should have been enough.

Comment: @DebanjanB That's copy and pasted (including formatting) from the exact close message. If you have a problem with the formatting, you should probably discuss that with the SO staff via meta. Did you look at your own message formatting before complaining about my message formatting?

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
No marshaller for signature of signal 'PropertiesChanged'
```

...implies that possibly the CentOS box have crashed.

As per [this discussion](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3702) heavy **Samba Server** file requests from any windows server (30+ file open and close requests per second from windows) would crash the the **CentOS5.2** box with the following backtrace:

```
PID: 5466 TASK: ffff810c1cdd1080 CPU: 7 COMMAND: "smbd"
 #0 [ffff810c1ac4ba70] crash_kexec at ffffffff800aa977
 #1 [ffff810c1ac4bb30] __die at ffffffff800650af
 #2 [ffff810c1ac4bb70] do_page_fault at ffffffff80066aa1
 #3 [ffff810c1ac4bc60] error_exit at ffffffff8005dde9
    [exception RIP: list_del+8]
    RIP: ffffffff801467f9 RSP: ffff810c1ac4bd18 RFLAGS: 00010002
    RAX: 0000000000200200 RBX: ffff810c1e1a5c78 RCX: 0000000000000001
    RDX: ffff810c1ac4bd24 RSI: ffffffff802ef1b0 RDI: ffff810c1e1a5c78
    RBP: ffff810c1e1a5c40 R8: ffff810c1ac4a000 R9: 0000000000000030
    R10: ffff8106350fb770 R11: 00002b8967ee6b20 R12: ffff810c1ac4be78
    R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000009 R15: 000000000000000a
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff CS: 0010 SS: 0018
 #4 [ffff810c1ac4bd20] free_uid at ffffffff80095c05
 #5 [ffff810c1ac4bd40] __sigqueue_free at ffffffff80096010
 #6 [ffff810c1ac4bd50] __dequeue_signal at ffffffff80096533
 #7 [ffff810c1ac4bd90] dequeue_signal at ffffffff80097641
 #8 [ffff810c1ac4bdc0] get_signal_to_deliver at ffffffff8002adca
 #9 [ffff810c1ac4be00] do_notify_resume at ffffffff8005aa43
#10 [ffff810c1ac4bf50] int_signal at ffffffff8005d32e
    RIP: 00002b8964d73f82 RSP: 00007fff476aedb8 RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000000000ea RCX: ffffffffffffffff
    RDX: 00000000ffffffff RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
    RBP: 00002b8964f87280 R8: 00002b8964f87280 R9: 00007fff476aedd0
    R10: 00002b8967ee6b20 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000001
    R13: 0000000000049538 R14: 0000000000002774 R15: 00002b896be1dd90
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000075 CS: 0033 SS: 002b
```

In those case the solution was to:

- Upgrade to **CentOS 5.3** or above.
- Upgrade to **Samba 3.0.33** or above.

Further as per the discussion in [Firefox will not start after version upgrade](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1223334) *Firefox* have crased earlier without any apparent reason. In those cases, a clean reinstall of *Firefox* will solve your issue.